Insert values without naming propertie names
In my Spring Boot application I'm using JDBI with the SQL Object style for database operations. I would like to have a simple way of inserting values into my database without writing out the property names in the statement. As far as I'm aware of  JDBI does not support something like that out of the box so I thought I could create something like this:
public interface PersonDao {
    @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO Person VALUES <columns>")
    void insert(Person person);
}

My idea now is to create a custom TemplateEngine, then use reflection at the start of my application to create a Bean holding a String with the property names, inject that into the TemplateEngine and replace the <columns> variable there like this:
public CustomEngine implements TemplateEngine {
    private final TemplateEngine defaultEngine = new DefinedAttributeTemplateEngine();
    @Autowired private Map<Class<?>, String> propertyMapping;

    @Override
    public String render(String template, StatementContext ctx) {
        var type = // get type of return Value
        var properties = propertyMapping.get(type);

        template.replace("<columns>", properties);
        return defaultEngine.render(template, ctx);
    }
}

The last thing I'm not entirely sure about is how to get the type of the return value. Can I get it from the StatementContext somehow? Or is there a better way to do this?

Hello and to give a quick answer on this, when interacting with databases this isn't a feature that is added because it is more of a security risk than a benefit. It has to do with the way the SQL statements will be built by the tools and to make sure that they are sanitized. By doing something like what you are trying you are leaving open a vuneralbility where certain statements could get injected into the SQL causing attackers to try and access data they shouldn't or just be mean and delete data. Let me know if you have any questions.

Also to add why it isn't worth it is most the time if a sql statment is getting changed in this way, the actual db is changing so chances are code connecting to it and mapping data will also need to be updated. This then leads to of course wanting to update and retest everything to make sure any updates work without bugs. So long story short, these changes are very rarely made in a relax nature where updating a simple property would be all that is needed
